# How to add dropdown/nested menu in backstage table

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, nested, dropdown, backstage

I need some help on Backstage.io
I created a plugin that has a table in it. I created it using Backstage table library.
Now I want to add a nested menu/details in each row.
So far I didn't find any documentation from Backstage itself.
How do you add it?

I've checked the official Backstage documentation, but didn't find anything.
There is not yet a lot of docs about dropdown/nested for Backstage